# Is my pdf file encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: pdf, character-encoding

I would like to find out, if a pdf file is encoded in UTF-8. How to check, which caracter encoding is used in a pdf file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A PDF is a binary file, not a text file.

A character encoding like "UTF-8" makes only sense in context with text files (*.txt, *.html, *.xml, *.csv, ...).

Thus, a PDF never is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 2):

PDF (before version 2.0) -files can be *either* a 8-bit binary file *or* a 7-bit ASCII(-85) text file. ([www.Prepressure.com/pdf/basics/fileformat](http://www.Prepressure.com/pdf/basics/fileformat) is a good article describing the PDF file format in more detail).

In 2017 the "PDF 2.0" standard (ISO 32000-2) was released, which, amongst other changes, offered utf-8 encoding as an additional text string format.
The PDF Association has more information: [www.pdfa.org/understanding-utf-8-in-pdf-2-0](http://www.pdfa.org/understanding-utf-8-in-pdf-2-0)

In short: *it depends* (on which PDF standard the question is referring to- in regards to the "text string" of the file).

Comment: *"PDF (before version 2.0) -files can be either a 8-bit binary file or a 7-bit ASCII(-85) text file."* - Both 1.x and 2.0 PDF files can be stored using only bytes from the ASCII range. That doesn't make them ASCII text files, though. It merely means that you can then transport those files via channels made for ASCII text. The prepressure article you link is inaccurate in a number of other details, too. For example there is no general restriction of the line length to 255 characters, merely outside of stream contents and outside of signature values. And even there it's nothing to count on...

Comment: *"PDF 2.0 ... offered utf-8 encoding as an additional text string format"* - yes, as encoding for string objects in the PDF structure. But again, this doesn't make the PDF file UTF-8 encoded, merely certain parts in it can be. In short, therefore, it still _does not depend_, a PDF file is _not_ an UTF-8 encoded file even if you can design it so that it can be parsed into a string using an UTF-8 decoder.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have amended my comment above to relate to the text-string, as opposed to the file structure of the "PDF-file" itself.