FastAPI returns PDF file, but OpenAPI-generated Python client raises UnicodeDecodeError when receiving binary data
I'm building a system where a FastAPI server endpoint returns a PDF file as binary data and I have used OpenAPI Generator Python to generate the client (7.6.0, 7.9.0 versions). However, when I call the endpoint using the generated client, I encounter a UnicodeDecodeError because the client tries to decode the binary PDF data as UTF-8 text.
After trying multiple options I am completely stuck and I would greatly appreciate pointing in the right direction. What I've tried:

Attempted to pass
_preload_content=False to prevent the client from automatically decoding the response. However, this results in a Pydantic
validation error since the generated client method does not accept
_preload_content as a parameter.
Using StreamingResponse: Tried returning a StreamingResponse from
the FastAPI endpoint. The issue remained the same.
Testing via API
docs and curl: When testing the endpoint using the FastAPI docs UI
or with curl, the response is correctly received as a PDF file.

Server-side code (FastAPI endpoint):
> from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, BackgroundTasks
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, StreamingResponse
import os

router = APIRouter()

> @router.get(
>     "/purchases/{order_id}/shipment_page",
>     responses={
>         200: {
>             "description": "PDF file response",
>             "content": {
>                 "application/pdf": {
>                     "schema": {
>                         "type": "string",
>                         "format": "binary"
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     } ) async def get_shipment_page_route(order_id: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
>     temp_file_path = f"temp_purchase_{order_id}.pdf"
>     try:
>         # Fetch the PDF content (binary data)
>         pdf_content = get_shipment_page(order_id)  # Returns bytes
>         
>         # Write the PDF content to a temporary file
>         with open(temp_file_path, "wb") as temp_file:
>             temp_file.write(pdf_content)
>         
>         headers = {
>             "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename=Purchase_{order_id}.pdf",
>         }
> 
>         # Schedule the temporary file for deletion after the response is sent
>         background_tasks.add_task(remove_file, temp_file_path)
> 
>         # Return the PDF file as a FileResponse
>         return FileResponse(
>             path=temp_file_path,
>             filename=f"Purchase_{order_id}.pdf",
>             media_type="application/pdf",
>             headers=headers
>         )
>     except Exception as e:
>         if os.path.exists(temp_file_path):
>             os.remove(temp_file_path)
>         raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
> 
> def remove_file(path: str):
>     if os.path.exists(path):
>         os.remove(path)

Client-side code (using OpenAPI-generated client):
import retumilo_client
from retumilo_client.rest import ApiException
import frappe
import logging


configuration = retumilo_client.Configuration(...)

def get_purchase_order_shipment_page(order_id: str):
    with retumilo_client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
        # Create an instance of the API class
        api_instance = retumilo_client.DefaultApi(api_client)

        try:
            # Attempt to get the PDF content
            pdf_content = api_instance.get_shipment_page_route_purchases_order_id_shipment_page_get(order_id)
            return pdf_content
        except ApiException as e:
            logger.error(f"Exception when calling DefaultApi: {e}")
            raise ValueError("Failed to get shipment page")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
            raise ValueError("An unexpected error occurred")

Traceback
22:26:38 web.1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
22:26:38 web.1      |   File "apps/xxxx_integration/xxxx_integration/xxxx_integration/integration/purchase_order.py", line 81, in get_purchase_order_shipment_page
22:26:38 web.1      |     pdf_content = api_instance.get_shipment_page_route_purchases_order_id_shipment_page_get(order_id)
22:26:38 web.1      |   File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/validate_call_decorator.py", line 59, in wrapper_function
22:26:38 web.1      |     return validate_call_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
22:26:38 web.1      |   File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_validate_call.py", line 81, in __call__
22:26:38 web.1      |     res = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(pydantic_core.ArgsKwargs(args, kwargs))
22:26:38 web.1      |   File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/retumilo_client/api/default_api.py", line 1157, in get_shipment_page_route_purchases_order_id_shipment_page_get
22:26:38 web.1      |     return self.api_client.response_deserialize(
22:26:38 web.1      |   File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/retumilo_client/api_client.py", line 318, in response_deserialize
22:26:38 web.1      |     response_text = response_data.data.decode(encoding)
22:26:38 web.1      | UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 197: invalid start byte


encode your pdf with utf-8 ? or see what is encoding type of file

What do you mean by that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115883/is-my-pdf-file-encoded-in-utf-8
The pdf file itself is not created by me, however download works correctly when I am using requests or curl anyway, so the issue has to be on openapi-generator side.

The issue is inside the retumilo_client code.  There must be a way to tell it to return a binary result instead of automatically assuming it is text.

@TimRoberts correct - retumilo_client is generated by https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator. The issue is that I don't know how to "tell it" that it is a binary.

There is also no reason to write the file to disk - you can just use Response with a content-type and output the binary data directly. Did you try to type your endpoint as returning bytes? (-> bytes) or just response_class=Response or -> Response?

Sorry, but no one here wants to debug AI-generated code.
